# Laravel graphql Upsert Directive not working as expected

Tags: laravel, graphql, directive, upsert, lighthouse

Please Correct me if I am wrong.

I have two models "Users" and "Profiles"

*Scenario 1:*

In the "Profiles" model I have defined "user_id" as primary key and foreign key to "users.id"

```
class Profile extends Model
{


    /**
     * primary key
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'country'
    ];
```

at schema.graphql

```
type Mutation {
    upsertProfile(user_id: ID, country: String): Profile @upsert
}

type Profile {
    user_id: ID!
    country: String
    user: User @belongsTo
}
```

Let's suppose there is an id **28** in users table. When I try to run mutation:

```
mutation {
    upsertProfile(user_id: 28, country: "India") {
    country
  }
}
```

It works fine and updates the country, but if there is no user_id **28** exists, as per definition it should create one.

As it defines **the user_id column is not an auto-increment column**

**I did one more test**

*Scenario 2:*

I removed 'user_id' as the primary key and added the id column as the primary key and **auto-increment**.
 Let suppose id 1 is there, then after running the mutation:

```
mutation {
    upsertProfile(id: 1, country: "India") {
    country
  }
}
```

I got the expected result.
But when I try to run mutation

```
mutation {
    upsertProfile(user_id: 28, country: "India") {
    country
  }
}
```

I am getting duplicates of result with new id everytime(auto-increment) whenever I ran this mutation.

My question,

1. How to use upsert if user_id exists then update the row, else create a row.
2. As laravel createOrUpdate function prototype contains checking on multiple columns to get a row updated, is there any way to do the same on upsert directive.

BTW, at *scenario 1* I debugged query and found that insert query is running but I am getting an exception at the grpahql-playground result

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Profile] 0",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "upsertProfile"
      ],
      ....
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ID attribute is fillable/unguarded.

Comment: I already marked user_id (primary key) enabled (fillable). Here is my model
```

class Profile extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',  'country'
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I recommend looking at the database queries to get an idea of what happens.

Comment: up till now, I got something stage like insert query is running but not inserting to the database table, it seems like begin transaction is not committed.

Comment: Ya means the error is "No query results for model [App\\Models\\Profile] 0", which I already mentioned. In my option when transaction runs and not committed the query returns 0 id, because no query was executed.

Comment: You can try to change the config setting `transactional_mutations = false,` in `lighthouse.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a timestamp issue. I put this line of code in my model and problem was solved

```
public $timestamps = false;
```